# python + how to verify if variable include charecter

Tags: python, linux

I created the following simple python script that runs on linux - python ver 2.X

```
 #!/usr/bin/python


 def GetListfiles():
        LS = (commands.getstatusoutput(" ls  "))
        return LS 

 AA = GetListfiles()

 for filename in AA:
       print "------------"
       print filename
```

after I run my script I get this output:

```
file.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

why I not get output as like this?

```
------------
file.txt
------------
file1.txt
------------
file2.txt
```

what I need to change in my code  ?

Comment: Do you specifically want to run a command, or are you just doing that to get the list of files?

Comment: Strange, considering `getstatusoutput` returns a (status, output) tuple, I'd expect your program to print "---------" and an exit code and "---------" and "file.txt" and "file1.txt" and "file2.txt". It's extremely unusual that you're not seeing any hyphens. Are you 100% sure that this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: yes I want to run any command in the (......) not only ls

Comment: @Kevin it does when I run it.

Comment: You script is wrong, and you do not execute it. It should not even run because of a missing `import commands`. I guess you called it `ls` or something like it and are executing some other command instead of it. Just add a `print '------\nIN SCRIPT\n--------`  before the `def` line, and look whether the message appears.

Comment: yes kevin I am sure 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the file names.

```
commands.getstatusoutput(" ls  ")
```

returns a tuple - 2 items that looks like this:

```
(0, 'filename.txt\nfilename1.txt\nfilename2.txt')
```

so it is prinitng `-----` then `0`, `-----` again and then the string `filename.txt\nfilename1.txt\nfilename2.txt` which appears as this:

```
--------------
0
--------------
filename.txt
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
```

So to get one line between each, do this:

```
def GetListfiles():
    LS = (commands.getstatusoutput(" ls  "))
    return LS

AA = GetListfiles()

AA = AA[1].split('\n')

for filename in AA:
    print "---------------"
    print filename
```

To check the file name includes the text `txt`, do this:

```
for filename in AA:
    print "---------------"
    if "txt" in filename:
        print filename
```

Comment: another simple question - how to verify after the line "for filename in AA" if filename var contain ".txt" file ?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're intending in pure Python:

```
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('*')

for filename in filenames:
    print "------------"
    print filename
```

Comment: Why / why not? Just curious.